# Parse a certificate signing request (CSR) with openssl API

Tags: openssl, x509, pem, csr

Im working in a project in which I receive a .csr file in pem format and I need to sign it in order to create a x509v3 signed certificate. I cant use the X509_sign() method in openssl because I need to use a third party signing service, I need to send the data to sign(in this case the .csr) file and it will return me the signature (sha256 with rsa).

My main problem is that I can not figure out how to open a CSR in memory, I mean, I know how to create or load an x509 certificate using the openssl API but I cant find how to load a CSR in order to use all the methods to retrieve all the data from the CSR and send it to my third party tool to sign it. If I can load the csr, i will be able to sign it and create a brand new x509.

Comment: Take a look at the source code for `openssl req` program in `<openssl src>/apps/req.c`. If you use the `-x509` switch, you get a signed certificate (assuming the other appropriate switches are present). If the command lacks the `-x509` switch, then you get a CSR.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know that exist apps/ which show you how the openssl commands are implemented. It is very helpful. :)

Comment: Yeah, OpenSSL is full of self documenting code. Often, the programs in the `app` directory are all you have.

Answer (score -1):

I think I found the answer:
http://www.umich.edu/~x509/ssleay/x509_reqs.html

The function is: PEM_read_X509_REQ(). I didn't try it yet, but Im pretty sure that with this function you can access to the CSR data structure as the same way as PEM_read_X509() allows you to access to the data structure of a x509 certificate.

Best regards.