# How to parse a CSR object using openssl API

Tags: c++, openssl, csr

I have an std::string which contains the CSR file's content.
The problem is that I can't find a way to parse this string into an object.
I've already tried the answers to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543855/parse-a-certificate-signing-request-csr-with-openssl-api) but they're only for a FILE.

I'm currently using this method but it always returns NULL.

```
const unsigned char * certChar = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(certStr.c_str());

X509* csr = d2i_X509(NULL, &certChar, certStr.size());
if (csr == NULL)
{
        std::cout << "Return value was NULL" << std::endl;
}
```

The loaded file in memory is a .CSR with the content put into the certStr std::string.

Using the ERR_get_error() method, i got the following error: **error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag**

Comment: The documentation suggests that you can use `ERR_get_error` together with `ERR_error_string` to see what went wrong. Does that give you any clues?

Comment: @Botje First thank you for this precious information ! So, I got the following error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag . I presume that my format wasn't good. I checked and saw that I had "\n" in the string. But even with them removed, it still doesn't work.

Comment: So what does `certStr` look like? If you write it to a file, can `openssl x509` do something with it?

Comment: If your `certStr` is actually in PEM format (eg it begins with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----`), you will need to decode it from PEM first. I think you can use `BIO_new_mem_buf` together with `PEM_read_bio_X509_REQ` for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Botje, I figured how to make it work.

```
BIO* bio = BIO_new_mem_buf(reinterpret_cast<const void*>(certStr.c_str()),certStr.size());
X509_REQ* csr;
PEM_read_bio_X509_REQ(bio, &csr, NULL, NULL);
```